# Error in iTEXT (java version)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, itext, digital-signature

When I am trying to write this code, it compiles fine but gives error in run time
(I am using iTEXT 5.3.5 -> http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/) :

```
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = af.verifySignature(name);
```

And the error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/tsp/TimeStampTokenInfo
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2312)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2265)
    at VerifyDoc2.<init>(VerifyDoc2.java:23)
    at VerifyDoc2.main(VerifyDoc2.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 4 more
Java Result: 1
```

Does anybody has any idea what I am doing wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Essentially the same problem as your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011104/error-in-verifying-digital-certificate-using-itext).

Comment: Down voting because this is a duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: Even I got down voting I am happy, at least I am getting more feedback which was not present in the previous page. I do not care for voting, I care for learning, I am a newbie....And thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

I have to used this following jar ------

bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.47
bctsp-jdk15-1.46.jar
itextpdf-5.3.5.jar
junit-4.11.jar
xmlworker-1.2.1.jar

I do not why it happens and why it was solved, but it works...If anybody got some help from this please give me plus. I got down voting and now I cannot post any more topic.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the bouncy castle libraries to your classpath.  E.g.

- bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar
- bctsp-jdk16-1.46.jar

You can download the bouncycastle libraries from [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html)

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown because `iText` can't find the necessary BouncyCastle-Classes within your classpath.

You need to add the BouncyCastle libraries, which you can download [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html)

Also please mark some of your SO-questions as answered.

Comment: This is the answer:

I have to used this following jar ------

bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.47
bctsp-jdk15-1.46.jar
itextpdf-5.3.5.jar
junit-4.11.jar
xmlworker-1.2.1.jar

I do not why it happens and why it was solved, but it works...If anybody got some help from this please give me plus. I got down voting and now I cannot post any more topic.